# C# ping minecraft

Tags: c#, php, ping, minecraft

So found this little code snippet that would allow you to ping a Minecraft server in PHP, but now i want to do this in C#.

I tried doing this on my own but for some reason its just not working

```
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        IPEndPoint ep;
        try
        {
            ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("-snip-"), -snip-);
            client.Connect(ep);
        }
        catch { Console.WriteLine("Error"); Console.ReadLine(); return; }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        bytes[0] = (byte)0xFE;
        client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
        IPEndPoint rep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        byte[] recv = client.Receive(ref rep);
        Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recv));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The server seems to just completely ignore the packet. This is the code snippet i found:

```
    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!$fp) return false;

    //Send 0xFE: Server list ping

    fwrite($fp, "\xFE");

    //Read as much data as we can (max packet size: 241 bytes)
    $d = fread($fp, 256);

    //Check we've got a 0xFF Disconnect
    if ($d[0] != "\xFF") return false;
```

Could anyone please point out what mistake i'm making? Thank you!

Comment: probably want to remove the IP considering this is a completely public place.

Comment: The first code snippet is what i built in C#, the second one is the snippet in PHP which i found here somewhere on stackoverflow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described [here](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping)

> The client initiates a **TCP** connection to the minecraft server on the
>   standard port. Instead of doing auth and logging in (as detailed in
>   Protocol Encryption), it sends the two byte sequence FE 01. This is a
>   0xFE server list ping packet. If the second byte (the 0x01) is
>   missing, the server waits about 1000ms then replies with the Server ->
>   Client format used in 1.3 and earlier.

you need to send a TCP request whereas you're sending an UDP packet...

Comment: Oh wow, i figured since minecraft uses the UDP protocol, it would also use the UDP protocol for the ping packet. Thank you!

Comment: @user2073973 Good form is to accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Yaur Ah yes, i tried voting your answer up but it said i needed 15 rep, i am kind of new to stackoverflow. I marked your answer as the solution now.