# Minecraft Server Ping with C#

Tags: c#, server, ping, tcpclient, minecraft

I tried to communicate with Minecraft Server by using C#. What I try to do is receive information about server *(name, motd, icon etc.)* by pinging it like a client. I used information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693583/c-sharp-ping-minecraft) and [here](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping) but I can't get this to work.

I can connect and send bytes to it but when I read the response from server I get only a byte "00FF". There's no error's or anything.

What am I doing wrong?

**Sample code I'm using:**

```
try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 25565);
            NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected.");

            if (netStream.CanWrite)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing...");
                byte[] bytes = { 0xFE };
                netStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Written.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't write to the stream!");
            }

            if (netStream.CanRead)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading...");
                byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                netStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                richTextBox1.AppendText(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));

                Console.WriteLine("Read.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't read from the stream!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Closing...");
            netStream.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Closed.");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I found out that I was trying to do legacy style ping. It's not working anymore and Ican't find nowhere an updated pinger. I need to send following data but I don't know how to do it:

```
1. FE — packet identifier for a server list ping
2. 01 — server list ping's payload (always 1)
3. FA — packet identifier for a plugin message
4. 00 0B — length of following string, in characters, as a short (always 11)
5. 00 4D 00 43 00 7C 00 50 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 48 00 6F 00 73 00 74 — the string MC|PingHost encoded as a UTF-16BE string
6. XX XX — length of the rest of the data, as a short. Compute as 7 + len(hostname), where len(hostname) is the number of bytes in the UTF-16BE encoded hostname.
7. XX — protocol version, e.g. 4a for the last version (74)
8. XX XX — length of following string, in characters, as a short
9. ... — hostname the client is connecting to, encoded as a UTF-16BE string
10. XX XX XX XX — port the client is connecting to, as an int.
```

The full connection info can be found [here](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#1.6), but I don't know how to implement this on C#.

This is NOT duplicate because all other questions are for the legacy way.

Comment: You may get better help over at [the Forge forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php) as the people who understand the innards of the server network system frequent there more than here.

Comment: That character is a 0xFF so according to your linked question you get a disconnect.

Comment: don't you need to read the bytes in a while loop or something..? check here how to properly read network stream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097269/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-from-networkstream-in-net

Comment: @MethodMan Tried that, same result.

Comment: @Draco18s Opened a topic there.

Comment: FYI, wiki.vg also has an IRC, [`#mcdevs`](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mcdevs&uio=d4).  They'll probably be able to help you.